# Is there any function in PHP to convert all of the Eastern European fonts into standard english?

Tags: php

> A¤ to a
>
> A¥ to a
>
> A„ to a
>
> A… to a
>
> A¶ to o
>
> A¸ to o
>
> A– to o
>
> A˜ to o
>
> A– to o
>
> Ã¶ to o
>
> A© to e
>
> Ã© to e
>
> A¦ to ae
>
> A¼ to u
>
> ø to o
>
> ä to a
>
> å to a
>
> ö to o
>
> æ to ae
>
> é to e
>
> é to e
>
> Å to a
>
> Ã© to e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one of my stupid idea, how to do it**

I am Czech myself, so some pages have issues when showing my special characters. So I created conversion table:

```
    function backToEnglish($text)
  {
    $chars_table =  Array('ä'=>'a','Ä'=>'A','á'=>'a','Á'=>'A','č'=>'c','Č'=>'C','č'=>'c','Č'=>'C','ď'=>'d','Ď'=>'D','ě'=>'e','Ě'=>'E','é'=>'e','É'=>'E',
'ë'=>'e','Ë'=>'E','í'=>'i','Í'=>'I','ľ'=>'l','Ľ'=>'L','ń'=>'n','Ń'=>'N','ň'=>'n','Ň'=>'N','ó'=>'o','Ó'=>'O','ö'=>'o','Ö'=>'O','ř'=>'r','Ř'=>'R','ŕ'=>'r','Ŕ'=>'R',
'š'=>'s','Š'=>'S','ś'=>'s','Ś'=>'S','ť'=>'t','Ť'=>'T','ú'=>'u','Ú'=>'U','ů'=>'u','Ů'=>'U','ü'=>'u','Ü'=>'U','ý'=>'y','Ý'=>'Y','ž'=>'z','Ž'=>'Z','ź'=>'z',
'Ź'=>'Z');

     return strtr($text, $chars_table);

  }
```

**it backfires when someone sends there character which is not covered** - as strong as you make it.

example on my name:

```
  $my_czech_name = "Pavel Janíček";
  $my_english_name = backToEnglish($my_czech_name);
  echo $my_english_name
```

Will return `Pavel Janicek`

Comment: No problem :) And as you can see on the example: Not covered character will pass through unchanged

Answer (score 0):

take look at function [convert_cyr_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-cyr-string.php)  - might help you. Or at least some of the comments below given function

Comment: write your own conversion table, but that is really really bad idea

Comment: Yes, That would be last thing. As I am fetching results from database, is there any way that it convert special characters to standard English while insertion or updation.

Comment: being pretty newbie myself, I went to the last one ... see my another answer how I did approach it. But its my maximum knowledge... btw, proper encoding on the database level could help you